# Обрезается часть текста в ВК, хотя в консоли все отлично

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Кусок кода:

```
for each in lessons:
    print(each.text.strip())
```

Вывод в консоли:
1 тест
2 тест
3 тест

Но, тем временем в ВК:

```
message="{}".format(each.text.strip()),
```

Вывод:
3 тест

*Что не так?* Может, format как-то негативно влияет на это всё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lessons = ["1 тест", "2 тест", "3 тест"]

for each in lessons:
    print(each.strip())
    message="{}".format(each.strip())

print("Message is: {}".format(message))
```

> *OUT:*
> 1 тест
> 2 тест
> 3 тест
> Message is: 3 тест

---

`lessons` это массив. Циклом `for` мы перебираем все его элементы и выводим на экран. Но каждая итерация цикла **перезаписывает** `message`. Он поочередно принимает значения `lessons`, а в конце остается на последнем значении - `тест 3`.

Вы должны **обновлять** `message` через `message += each.text` или использовать что-то в роде `"".join(lessons)`

---

<sub>Не работал с *vk api* в питоне, так что могу ошибаться</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Кажется вы забыли цикл в сообщении для вк, должно быть как то так

```
full_text = ""
for each in lessons:
  full_text += each  
message="{}".format(full_text.strip())
```

или

```
message="{}".format("".join(lessons).strip())
```